# Why does my regex have length 2?

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote this regex with the idea that it will match any string in its entirety and simple return the whole string as the result.

The character class `[^]` containing the carrot asks for a match of all characters starting with anything exclude nothing.  The `*` says let this happen any number of times.

But, my result matches the full string twice.  I expect one match.  What is wrong?

```
var regex = /([^]*)/;
var someString = "blahdy blah blah";
var result;

result = regex.exec(someString);
//why does this have a length of 2?  I expect only 1 containing the entire string
console.log(result.length);
console.log(result);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/b4uue/2/)

Comment: I am surprised that this thing even compiles. Must be a js thing.

Comment: @FailedDev It won't work if the browser lacks an error console.  IE is the only browser I am aware of that does not have one.  Replace `console.log` with `document.writeln`

Comment: You need to read the documentation for `.exec()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec.  It's all explained there.  `.match()` works the same way.

Comment: what's wrong with `/.*/m`? - certainly makes more sense to **me**

Comment: @Code Jockey - I agree.  To me this is more explicit.  I chose a character class because that is how Douglas Crockford does it in his book.  When I asked the question I was not sure if the issue lied with this abstract way of selecting all characters or somewhere else.  I did tinker a bit and notice that removing the carrot kills the match.  So at least in JavaScript's RegEx compiler carrot means more than simply "start at the beginning of the string" as I am accustomed to in C#.

Comment: inside a character class (the `[]`), the `^` never means "beginning of line" or similar -- it either means negation of the character class, or a literal `^` - I wouldn't be surprised, though, if some flavor of regex somewhere at least stumbled on the negated empty character class (saying something like "not... ummm not what now?"), if it doesn't somehow interpret it as a character class matching only `^` characters. It seems risky, but if you only stick to JavaScript, there may be no problem... *may... be...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing capturing (the `()` inside the pattern), which means the regex call will return both the captured data (the whole string), as well as the entire string that caused the regex to match (again, the whole string).

Comment: I assume this is some feature of 'exec()`?  So, does the exec have a common place where the whole string is set?  I mean is this always placed at index 0?

Comment: It's a feature of every regex engine that I know of, index 0 is always the string that caused the matches. indexes 1+ are the capture groups (index 1 = first capture group, index 2 = second capture, etc...).